# MS Access query too complex to be evaluated

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

This query is used to call a specific set of work requests over a period of time, this query takes date inputs and the system number from a form. The query result is then put into another form to view.

I've gone over all VBA code that is relevant to this and there seems to be no problems there however so I have determined that the query is too complex and as I am not too well versed in SQL I am not too sure where to go from here.

This Query also provides a #name? Error viewed in forms

The Query

```sql
SELECT tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.WO_REQ_NUMBER
    ,tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.WR_TASK_TITLE
    ,"Click Here" AS [Work Request Description]
    ,tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.SYSTEM_CODE
    ,tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.UNIT
    ,[tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ].[Unit] + "-" + [tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ].[SYSTEM_CODE] + "-" + [tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ].[EQUIPMENT_NUMBER] AS EQ_TAG
    ,tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.WO_REQ_STATUS
    ,CDate(Format([WO_REQ_DATE_ENTER], "@@@@\/@@\/@@")) AS WR_CREATION_DATE
FROM qryfrmOutput
INNER JOIN tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ ON qryfrmOutput.SCI = tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.SYSTEM_CODE
WHERE (
        ((tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.SYSTEM_CODE) = Forms ! frmOutputDarlington ! ListSelectedSystem)
        AND (
            (CDate(Format([WO_REQ_DATE_ENTER], "@@@@\/@@\/@@"))) >= Forms ! frmOutputDarlington ! TextStartDate
            AND (CDate(Format([WO_REQ_DATE_ENTER], "@@@@\/@@\/@@"))) <= (Forms ! frmOutputDarlington ! TextEndDate + 1)
            )
        );
```

The function that inserts the system code and date,

```vb
strSCI = ConcatRelated("[SCI]", "[tblSystemAssignmentList]", "[Facility] = '" & [TempVars]![varFacility] & "' AND [Selected] = True", , " OR ", "(tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.SYSTEM_CODE)='")
searchString = "(tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.SYSTEM_CODE)=Forms!frmOutputDarlington!ListSelectedSystem"
If InStr(1, SCIList, searchString) <> 0 Then
     SCIList = Replace(SCIList, "(tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.SYSTEM_CODE)=Forms!frmOutputDarlington!ListSelectedSystem", strSCI)
Else
    SCIList = Replace(SCIList, "(tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.SYSTEM_CODE)=[Forms]![frmOutputDarlington]![ListSelectedSystem]", strSCI)
End If
```

ConcatRelated

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset         
    Dim rsMV As DAO.Recordset   
    Dim strSQL As String            
    Dim strOut As String            
    Dim lngLen As Long              
    Dim bIsMultiValue As Boolean    


    ConcatRelated = Null


    strSQL = "SELECT " & strField & " FROM " & strTable
    If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If
    If strOrderBy <> vbNullString Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY " & strOrderBy
    End If
    Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

    bIsMultiValue = (rs(0).Type > 100)


    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If bIsMultiValue Then
            Set rsMV = rs(0).Value
            Do While Not rsMV.EOF
                If Not IsNull(rsMV(0)) Then
                    strOut = strOut & rsMV(0) & strSeparator
                End If
                rsMV.MoveNext
            Loop
            Set rsMV = Nothing
        ElseIf Not IsNull(rs(0)) And strFieldName = "(tblImportedSCRs.System) Like '*" Then
            strOut = strOut & strFieldName & rs(0) & "*'" & strSeparator
        ElseIf Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
            strOut = strOut & strFieldName & rs(0) & "'" & strSeparator
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close


    lngLen = Len(strOut) - Len(strSeparator)
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ConcatRelated = Left(strOut, lngLen)
    End If

exit_handler:

    Set rsMV = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "ConcatRelated()"
    Resume exit_handler
End Function
```

When I run the code it should output the requested reports within the requested timeframe, however instead of the actual values it displays #name?

Comment: The Replace() function code doesn't make sense. Can't reference a table directly so why using table prefix to field reference? Why are the parameters within quote marks? This results in a string of the references as literal text, not the values of those parameters. Have you step debugged?

Comment: I have stepped debugged, the error occurs on the end if of the first VBA code. I wish I could answer the other questions but I did not write the code.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, reduce the code and specify the parameters:

```sql
PARAMETERS
    Forms!frmOutputDarlington!ListSelectedSystem Long,
    Forms!frmOutputDarlington!TextStartDate DateTime,
    Forms!frmOutputDarlington!TextEndDate DateTime;

SELECT 
    tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.WO_REQ_NUMBER,
    tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.WR_TASK_TITLE,
    "Click Here" AS [Work Request Description],
    tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.SYSTEM_CODE,
    tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.UNIT,
    [tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ].[Unit] & "-" & [tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ].[SYSTEM_CODE] & "-" & [tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ].[EQUIPMENT_NUMBER] AS EQ_TAG,
    tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.WO_REQ_STATUS,
    DateValue([WO_REQ_DATE_ENTER]) AS WR_CREATION_DATE
FROM 
    qryfrmOutput
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ ON 
        qryfrmOutput.SCI = tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.SYSTEM_CODE
WHERE
    tbl_NIMSD_dbo_TIDWRREQ.SYSTEM_CODE = Forms!frmOutputDarlington!ListSelectedSystem
    AND
    DateValue([WO_REQ_DATE_ENTER]) >= Forms!frmOutputDarlington!TextStartDate
    AND
    DateValue([WO_REQ_DATE_ENTER]) <= DateAdd("d", 1, Forms!frmOutputDarlington!TextEndDate)
```

Comment: You may also enjoy my [DJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57288781/3527297) function.