# ConcatRelated function and the fifth argument

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to achieve the following:

If you have:

```
ItemNo   DocumentNo    Quantity
AB1         WS1           10
AB1         WS2           10
```

I want:

```
 ItemNo   DocumentNo    Quantity
AB1         WS1 | WS2          10
```

I'm not quite understanding how to use the fifth argument. I continue to get errors, stating that "|" is not valid.

Here's the code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Query3.ItemNo,  ConcatRelated("Query3.DocumentNo", "Query3", "Query3.ItemNo = " & [Query3.ItemNo] & " | " )
FROM Query3;
```

Here's the website:
http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell, but my *DJoin* function [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57288482/how-to-design-a-query-to-give-names-of-each-related-field-linked-to-each-set-of/57288781#57288781) and this query:

```sql
SELECT 
    ItemNo, 
    DJoin("[DocumentNo]","[Query3]","[ItemNo] = '" & [ItemNo] & "'"," | ") AS DocumentNos, 
    Quantity
FROM 
    Query3
GROUP BY 
    ItemNo, 
    Quantity
HAVING 
    Count(*) >=2;
```

will provide this output:

[image: Test]

Comment: Just letting you know that I'm waiting for the query to finish.

Comment: The process is slow. How many records do you have, and have you applied proper indexing? I only have your sample which, of course, takes no time.

Comment: My guess is a maximum of 200 for this iteration. But it varies widely depending on the day. You wouldn't happen to have a rough estimate as to how long this will take will you? Secondarily, if it is strenuous for Access, would you happen to know of a different database management system that would be faster?

Comment: If you browse my article on _DJoin_, [Join (concat) values from one field from a table or query](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33612/Join-concat-values-from-one-field-from-a-table-or-query.html), you'll see a test for timezones that runs in 2 seconds for 170,000 records in a local Access table.

Comment: So, you trimmed your query. Or?

Comment: Trimmed and it works perfectly! Thank you very much!--

Is it possible to show only the items with 2 documents or greater? I created a second query that calculates length (As each document no is 8 characters long).